# How to set remote repository which is cloud-JCR

Tags: jfrog-container-registry

I created a JCR remote-repo and when I try to set it's URL to point to another cloud-JCR, after clicking on the "test" button I receive error code "400 bad request".

The error on the 'source' JCR server is:

`[WARN ] (o.a.r.RemoteRepoBase:449) - cloud-remote: Error in getting information for 'node/8.10/list.manifest.json' (java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't fetch token for repo: cloud-remote realm: https://<server-name>-local.jfrog.io/<server-name>/api/docker/local/v2/token scope:repository:node:pull).`

Comment: Hi Sharon V, welcome to Stackoverflow! Please include a Minimal, Reproducible Example ( stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ) to help others find a solution to your problem

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are running into a known issue ([RTFACT-14607](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-14607)) with the test button of Docker "Smart Remote Repositories", that is, repositories pointing to other Artifactory instances. You can remote a JCR instance from another JCR instance though, to do this you will need to:

1. Set the correct URL (/{context}/api/docker/{repo-name}) - The context is typically `artifactory` for on-prem or server name on SaaS
2. Uncheck "Enable Token Authentication"
3. Set the credentials to a valid user with at least READ permission on the remote site(under the Advanced Tab)
4. Save (don't bother with the test button, it won't work)